# Apply function to all possible values of a variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, apply

I would like to get as many plots as factors/values in a variable.

For example, I would like to plot the following variables (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8) that I have defined as a scale for all possible values on the variable country. So i get, in that case,  a total of three different plots.

I know how to plot it separately, for example in this cases I would have used the following:

```
basicgraph(Data[country==1, scale1] )
basicgraph(Data[country==2, scale1] )
basicgraph(Data[country==3, scale1] )
```

I would like my function to plot as many graphs as factors/values (without specifying the number of factors/values).  I have tried with "apply" but i can't really make it work, so any clue could be good for me.

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  country
1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
2   5   5   5   5   5   4   5   5   2
3   4   5   3   5   4   5   5   5   3
4   5   5   5   4   2   4   4   5   1
5   4   3   5   4   4   5   4   5   2
6   5   5   5   2   3   4   3   5   3
7   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
8   3   5   5   5   4   5   4   4   2
9   4   5   5   4   5   5   4   5   3
10  2   4   4   5   4   5   4   5   1
11  4   5   5   3   4   4   4   5   2
12  4   5   4   4   5   4   4   5   3
13  5   5   4   3   3   5   5   5   1
14  3   5   1   2   3   1   4   5   2
```

Ihave defined the scale as:

```
scale1  <- names(Data) %in% c( "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8")
```

I have defined a plot function by:

```
basicgraph<-function(df, title, lab)

{

  for(i in 1:length(df))
  {
    y <- melt(df)
    z <- with(y, as.data.frame(table(variable, value, exclude = NULL)))
    z <- z[!is.na(z$variable), ]
    z$scale <- z$variable
    levelss<-levels(z$variable)

  }

theme_nogrid <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") 
      {
        theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
        theme(panel.grid = element_blank())   +
         theme(axis.text.x =element_text(size = base_size * 0.8 , lineheight = 0.9, 
                                         vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, angle=90))
       }

plot1<-function(z) { 
  ggplot(data = z, aes(x = variable, y = value, size = Freq))+
    geom_point(aes(size = Freq,  stat = "identity", position = "identity"), shape = 20, color="black", alpha=0.6) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,15)) + 
     scale_x_discrete(breaks=levelss,labels=lab)+   
    xlab("")+  #Afegir/canviar títol eix x
    ylab("Response")+ #Afegir/canviar títol eix y
    ggtitle(title)+  #Títol a dalt
    theme_nogrid()
}

}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that there is an error here :`scale1  <- names(Data) %in% c( "v1, "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8")`? The v1 is not enclosed.

Comment: I haven't notice, now is Edited,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty confusing question and example. I *think* you want to produce a different graph for each `country` value? In that case I'd suggest something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
Data_m <- melt(Data, id.vars="country")  # melt the data into 'long' format

f <- function(d) {  # function that produces a graph and waits
    print(qplot(variable, value, data=d) + ggtitle(unique(d$country)))
    readline()
}

library(plyr)
d_ply(Data_m, .(country), f)  # produces three separate graphs
```

The d_ply call splits `Data_m` into three parts and repeatedly calls `f` on each, producing a graph of that subset of the data, without knowing anything about the data being graphed.

Comment: I have tried your example and i only get 1 graph.. I don't know if I am doing it wrong, or it just doesn't work.

Comment: It does work; the only thing it assumes is that `Data` is your data frame above, and ggplot2 is loaded. You understand that you'll need to press RETURN after each plot to view the next? ...I've edited the code slightly so it displays the `country` number above each plot. HTH.

Comment: After trying, I made it work, when that happened I accepted your answer :)